# Allow Inheritance in Meta of Document

Tags: inheritance, mongoengine

If I have a Document:

```
class First(Document):
    field1 = StringField()
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class Second(First):
    field2 = StringField()
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['field2']
    }
```

Will this work?  I'm curious if the meta in Second will overwrite the allow_inheritance in First and will break the app.  It seems to work in testing but I'm not sure how this is handled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work.

`meta` *is not overriden, you can say it will be updated.*

When you instantiate a document from `Second` model, and `save()` it, will be saved in the `first` collection, and in that moment in `first` collection will be created the `field2` index.

More Details:

from the [source code](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/base/metaclasses.py#L248),
The class `Document` got a `metaclass=TopLevelDocumentMetaclass` which change the default action override to update, something like `attrs["_meta"].update(attrs.get("meta", {}))`